# Resultados da linhas em colunas ( SOMA )

Tags: php, mysql, query, select, pivot

Boa Tarde,
estou com uma grande duvida em minha query, tenho uma tabela com as seguintes info:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de obter o seguinte resultado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso que o resultado seja o valor total das (formas de pagamentos) por dia, dividido por período em duas colunas, M e N.

Acredito que seja uma query muito simples, mais estou quebrando a cabeça e não estou conseguindo.. já tentei utilizar todos os **GROUP BY**.

Encontrei algumas dica falando para usar o **PIVOT** mais não consegui fazer o **SUM** como essa ferramenta.

Consegui chegar nessa query, mais ainda não é o que quero, ela me traz o total do dia, não o total por período como quero

Minha Query:

`SELECT data, (SELECT format(SUM(valor),2,'de_DE') WHERE periodo = 'N') AS N, (SELECT format(SUM(valor),2,'de_DE') WHERE periodo = 'M') AS M FROM floja1 WHERE extract(month FROM data) = '05' GROUP BY data ORDER BY data`

Desde já agradeço.

Att;
Danilo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa noite Danillo. Tente a seguinte query:

```
select
    data,
    sum(if(periodo = 'M', valor, 0)) as 'M',
    sum(if(periodo = 'N', valor, 0)) as 'N'
from tabela
group by data
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! isso mesmo que queria!